# Appcelerator HTTPClient Request not authenticating with Server

Tags: android, appcelerator

I can't seem to figure this one out, and I've tried googling that my fingers now hurt.

I am performing a HTTPClient request to my Domino Server that has SSL enabled. My request works perfectly when testing on iOS, but fails every time when testing through the Android Emulator and Mobile Web.

I'm running Android 2.2 SDK.

When I try to sign in from the App, I am definitely reaching the Server, because HTML is returned (the Login Web Form). When HTML is returned, it either means that the Authentication failed, or that the Redirect didn't work. When signing in through iOS the page redirects 100%.

Below is my code:

```
var orderReq = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();
var myurl = 'https://domain/db.nsf?login';
orderReq.setEnableKeepAlive;
orderReq.open('POST',myurl, false);

var params = {
username: "Joe Smith",
password: "Password",
redirectto: "path/db.nsf/response.xsp"
};
orderReq.send(params);

var myreturn = orderReq.responseText;

if((myreturn.charAt(0) === '<') || (myreturn === ""))
{
Ti.API.info('Fail');
return 'Fail';

}
else
{
Ti.API.info('Pass');
var json = orderReq.responseText;
var response = eval('(' + json + ')');
return response.username;
}
```

I have tried many properties and to no avail. I can confirm that the Android Emulator can connect to the Internet. It feels like either the Parameters are not being passed or the Redirect is not being triggered on the Web Page.

**NOTE:** I notice when authenticating through Android emulator that it fails immediately, where iOS returns true or false after 1-2 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Okay i know the question is too old. But, for anyone who is looking for an answer, this is what worked for me.

1. Make sure params is stringified before sending it to the server

`orderReq.send(JSON.stringify(params));`

1. Include the following right after the lines - orderReq.open('POST',myurl, false);

`xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');`
`xhr.setRequestHeader('charset','utf-8');`